# Нормально ли в Kafka создать множество топиков для общения с сервисами?

Tags: архитектура, очередь, apache-kafka

У меня есть микросервисы и некий оркестратор, который управляет их работой.

Пытаюсь понять нормально ли поступать следующим образом:

1. К нам пришло сообщение на оркестратор через топик 1.
2. Оркестратор отправил сообщение в сервис 1 с помощью топика 2.
3. Далее оркестратор принимает обработанное сообщение от сервиса 1 через прослушивание топика 3.
4. Оркестратор делает свои какие-то операции над сообщением и отправляет его в сервис 2 через топик 4.
5. Получает результат от сервиса через топик 5.

Здесь мы на каждый ответ от сервиса управляем отдельной очередью. Нормально ли это? Не было бы лучше создать единую очередь с ответом и по типу ответа на оркестраторе понимать источник сообщения? Или все же лучше на каждый дополнительный сервис создать один топик на передачу и второй на принятие?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это нормально. Более того, это даже полезно со многих точек зрения, например:

- вы разделяете ответственности
- сервисам не нужно читать и фильтровать чужие сообщения, соответственно, вам не нужно кодировать эту логику, а сервисам не нужно тратить ресурсы на это
- вы облегчаете себе эволюцию контракта сообщений (за счет того, что один тип сообщения предназначен для одного сервиса)
- у топиков может быть разный retention time
- и т.д.

Что вызывает подозрение в вашем дизайне, так это следующие вещи:

- соотношение один к одному между производителем и потребителями
- наличие топиков для "запроса" и "ответа"

Оба этих пункта, конечно, имеют право на жизнь при определенных требованиях, например:

- в бизнес-процессе не нужна или даже противопоказана синхронность
- у вас есть пики в нагрузке, и вы хотите их буферизовать с помощью очереди

Если это не про вас, то может быть вам достаточно синхронного API?..